# Comparing value of a viewbag in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a school project all day and now I've I think a quite simple problem but I dont see it.

In my view file (details.cshtml) I try to compare a viewbag value.
`ViewBag.ScoreOne` contains a int

```
@if(Model.Turn == Model.PlayerOneId && ViewBag.ScoreOne <= 10){

}
else if (@Model.Turn == Model.PlayerTwoId && ViewBag.ScoreTwo <= 10)
{

}else{

}
```

I let the code in the statements out because it isn't usefull.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you get an exception? or do you get an unexpected result? Please post the error message and the description what should happen!

Comment: Your `@` before the `Model` is not necessary - that symbol is just to tell Razor that you're in a C# section, not HTML, and Razor already knows this based on where you're at. I don't know if that's your problem, but should still be dealt with.

Comment: thank you @JoeEnos I will correct it. The problem was that i forgot to debug..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast ((int)ViewBag.ScoreOne) the ViewBag's properties to int before comparing.